# SVG not getting rendered in react native using react-native-svg

Tags: react-native, svg

The following SVG is not getting rendered, all I can see is a blank screen.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SvgCss } from 'react-native-svg';

export default function SvgComponent(props) {
  const xml =  `<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><style>@font-face {font-family: 'C';src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABAAAAAAhYAA4AAAAAEaAAAAgAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP0ZGVE0cGh4GYACCUggEEQgKjXyKNQtAAAE2AiQDRgQgBYxYB2AbpA5RVJOqIfsiwTY1W/APIgxtajFaoUqBxftg5H7wSPuhL7n7lNwvEA+EIgZX2862bp7UHAk1YTZFJFzlHP3ANvvHdMW6WIUsutRl+md9wENc5FWVF3LZzQP/h/v7Rm3gTsfTLJ6cSDSmTssyGf9/0g+yAV+N/xfOsv/PvarZ/i04L3A8wQ0YwT/2y+hcg6ofuGNpaU7B4gTtKRap2jIWu4jnIJ/pLvFFAQL4uMxbD4B31OxVAH55zqcAAQl0AJQQAxARKNA4IZOoQD90DFhWXpV8CvETqLwBqHjEmyLApgAA8GDd1A5JMJVx3/++aO2jD3gEQP4jC4YgIODUF2NgDwnLcK3VSv04BUN4KkvflDy5cq0chtA6pAoim6IBCk8UBCGiiqxajBzl0aR8wNTvB5pzODKUS9nk1kHzOv9xIF9A74DVtFqFCvZqots1gDz7HGPpTZVer6PJhpJhc63TlIwbvGppMtZfXVqVpgk1z+p4zLXtfhPHrBYa3+q85hZ6eXbZ0mDGJ/ursr7LqGHmSx+h73IUHLki7D+Lovjt/Y3+i2rRZcHlgt3GfEKQxc+AIgH/asT1AWDhStbnOvG8o5vhGHQZRa9L/ycU1Sy9TQyzmsQ0H6qkaIp+G23pAtqFICYul7baBA0GGerqwc+LERGnk0LObc1fc6xs9Qm4idN7/kQFWnkEiis63Wgo5cQ6Xc0RE7al7XvSq9zIToXbdXIMbi9dgSosFVS6ePETSQkVZAun+A2afA/t5BfzhSy8CCwQLZ0lZYKNcokJeoqium0V8MuQSFaPpTMP2ZT58P4Xa3au8Fqx4uSKnRuWtDWB0t5SVwq2nThzhUa5lpnUt12rxjSOd59nm0+MPbVlKdLkdV5ttd5m5Vz3Ci9zgVdlDDWxY0fQqlMGAur/sXy+XAsNp7yis8rIUK4npCa2ZiPXOfpznmHHyo/hb6ZvH7cdlvhOP+07veespu+0xsCca5Jqluo+6D8j0Sq/24kAo9OVFFFmy/4SyRsFfnjRJy4eUzPuq1dtML2RDkkx8+QrIwZODoTD0pNy3D5Pxa/s75ykVBOd07vLaKF9jjTAsbo6KZkftyMhRZgclBQKrppnG+P7VsxaOiZ29OGrCvuBqoLiwro7DfzMCtA5xWqkCevsRfbHSwCy03dbiaw8GXYvmO2uUAkdsmW84+mhvLS4koTdSQmlqQnpeUlOqvaPQ8SocVR31yRqt7RnGugrw36FMSzj8MtBCVU5EkoycHdAQkmYu3B0+3VG9V9zX2JxfmnbWVvf1LC09k9i0NecMX22Yvzq+FLJeYZV4VqPeGC+g2Vyk4BLqzlZJyuzTrltotkuIooji+qBr8MubsW2Mix9UY2plWC6W9k3gTpE9o+me+hx8kOEclKXPCWGn8gmR/NTk+NLUtmkxFKwuFPOqMQ9Bgz7Xtwn72wJ2xox7KIqfCyY7qb7pynVivh0NCcuIvljTO+wiZRawczslHcvnbOsx/igc1ZCRFpW4upS/LXMRnbaNNsyrFE1Ka9OzW5LsjLeH7gkqPukKmwGGJ1pGi8VL2qp3bt+b1E+FZkZGGxtXvrx2dNtx7B9+WYXneuGWqvHliaH12WHCKPXePgl+5ebz7r2yy0bdHPZPCaPFb+AsRrmENE1UqGiR1P7lOP8xzG8PMORE3hgvlZ7pEHXCU3PSU03WPhwM3xUadtJn1Oc2N9VMT+4/sf/z97uCBLsr4MfBz4OHWtjCwep24rbA5pCsHwcX2hL2h5f2D2EBQ84w7cT7aGPPTq2NoU9iQEAXiOwZqDW5bISsllH+8dAzdFiJQQ2c7JZtNk8RTryR7QiXwEBgudXY2bVmcT91nMJzyeYxy6I+aeMb+M+TJjaQDCRY4FcARMDCG1kjBO4AigXF6oAeMe4ZvhwEyuVLSfVfGAqeAjmIJKDYMYGudJnXBMcAgbhOAAUCAEb4ACAnpBQ5fJtJhAQTb5BIW0EG8NkNRZ2BGT2x1XINSV7FMYTjVJbOoZKY/oDM53r4TrzTjXhVJnEjMsVsAxwiCFXoDSUCB4iRohGwiVkHmvpITcUv6OwK/mjNJXmozKQbsMcyoZwq/MYc3r6i1LJyDEIIm3aUTA+mvjChAgSLAimSANCgybtFCgtVkEPhtaNcfJCw3FtCDgMZ5KJl2LlJzL2sRakFoRhWjTDwYPb5jT5rvfkDx3o2dSuoFrWBexEk5az9XgbgR8dzIHT5MtfeizAARnSiEjlk5GS4cmvwNUiChJwYJgmkubLpDLeWSMfBV4dALhMRgInwWhN5aaQ8PU0IDEN2VuuFU9ztcp5JGw8TnIZjtaqgwglBN64rQSSCPhAXChCuGhweSHBJUyrTEqRdwYzVTpS3sprFkl5EplUht/san+6tUNEheC3xVodSoRHN8ZCN/taOFYzvTHBcEH6j49tJdKqRT34zm0WuQUtOCMWm8FYDYubydYGGKrRW5u1kLSG/emAkWkdbFpsmUux8rZiIhJr2AOK37t5Ss++OqS7rKuMDEGsGU1UvSWAoNxuhYhaKiWrQU3IEtlWSdxmdQVCh1RGYsJb6lbFUo0CYFNhvvmFGg8uJe8yXZYmWwEMXwslCkRE6xCHZrPIQipHrSh118ObxNKyC87XVFZEyP7wIoJxwsFR5GIEChyrpGBV24zjg29Sjk9VAPwPFQcQWmZwAeLxTTx48uLNhy8//gLw4ALHnQ8NESpMuAiRokSLEStOPAAA') format('woff2');font-weight: 500; font-style: normal; font-display: swap;}.f { width: 100%; height: 100%; }.b { fill: whitesmoke; }.a { animation: o 2s ease-out forwards; }@keyframes o { 10% { opacity: 1; } 100% { opacity: 0; } }tspan { fill: black; font-family: 'C'; font-size: 70px; text-transform: uppercase; text-anchor: middle; }</style><rect class='b f' /><svg y='525' overflow='visible'><text><tspan x='500'>inoculate the soul</tspan></text><text><tspan x='500'>------------------</tspan></text></svg><rect class='b f a' /></svg>`
  return (
    <SvgCss xml={xml}/>
  );
}
```

I have the svg as a string and how can I render the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall your package in ios and android

`cd ios && pod install && cd ..`

`cd android && ./gradlew clean build`

if you using react native below 0.60 you need to auto-link the package given in the documentation.

https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to import SVG and use it ... Till now I have used two  ways..

1.

```
import Svgxyz from "../../assets/svg/svg_xyz.svg"; //Import in this way

//Use it as a component
<Svgxyz />
```

2. import Svgxyz from "../../assets/svg/svg_xyz.svg"; //Import in this way

   import { SvgXml } from "react-native-svg";

   //Use it in this way

If you are using TypeScript you have to declare it first:
Create a file in root named:

svg.d.ts

Paste this inside that file

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');
  export const ReactComponent: 
  React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

If nothing works: Try building the app again after doing a gradle clean.

Answer (score -1):

try it dude. Also install pods if you run on İOS'cd ios' then 'pod install', also dont forget 'npm install react-native-svg'

its works

import { SvgXml } from 'react-native-svg';

Comment: and usage.
<SvgXml xml={IMAGES.moneyIcon}  />

Comment: Yes, it works for most svg, but not for this one. Test it yourself, and even I tried using SvgCss